# Jackrabbit as a files storage

Tags: webdav, jackrabbit, jcr

Please help me to configure WebDAV server based on the Jackrabbit.

I need Java WebDAV server that you could just expand on the server with minimal effort. I searched for SO many offered to pay attention to the Jackrabbit. For the second day trying to figure out how to make it work as a WebDAV server.

Start the server on port 8082 and try to connect via WebDAV from windows Explorer. But to create folders cannot even from the user "admin".

I read the [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore#File_Data_Store). Did everything as it says (configuration). And now the main page on `localhost:8082` says that the jackrabbit not configured and offers a small form that leads to `localhost:8082/admin`. Only with this page gives a 404 error.

```
HTTP ERROR 404 
Problem accessing /admin/. Reason: 
NOT_FOUND
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to configure anything to experiment with Jackrabbit as a WebDAV server.

The simplest is to download the standalone jar from http://jackrabbit.apache.org/downloads.html (currently `jackrabbit-standalone-2.8.0.jar`) and start it with `java -jar jackrabbit-standalone-2.8.0.jar` in an empty folder.

Then, look at `http://localhost:8080/` which has instructions that lead you to connect your WebDAV client to `http://localhost:8080/repository/default/`

The http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore documentation that you refer to is about configuring how the Jackrabbit backend stores the files, you don't need to worry about that for initial experiments - such configurations are only needed later on when you need to tune Jackrabbit to your storage needs.